# running scripts without using python keyword

Tags: python, unix

I would like apologise since this is not exactly a programming releated question but rather something I would like to know :

I installed a python library with files say: lib.py, lib2.py .. lib-n.py. All these scripts take command line arguments when being called. So it looks like

`username@machinename:~$ lib.py -s <args> -t <args> ..`

Now like you can see above, I can run these scripts form any directory and without using the 'python' keyword before calling them. I would like to do this with the python scripts that I write as well. ie; I should be able to call them from any directory instead of 'cd'ing to their location.

P.S: Using a Linux machine running Ubuntu 12.04 and  python 2.7.3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts

Answer (score 3):

Add this to top of your script -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And then make your python script executable using `chmod` -

```
chmod u+x <python script>
```

Also, if you do not want to give complete path to python script, you can add the directory the script exists in to `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: ... and add that dir to `$PATH`.

Comment: To be picky, the variable is called `PATH`, `$PATH` gives the value (`$` being a unary operator).  Some consider the use of `/usr/bin/env` to be a security risk (because environment variables can be compromised, e.g. "shellshock"), and a safer `chmod` is to use `u+x`.

Comment: but if we do not use `/usr/bin/env` and instead use complete path to python, it may not work if python got moved